# Dynamic HTML In Angular

Tags: angular

I want to use dynamic button in html and on `click` of it I want to call a function in angular. I am using angular 7. Now i found solution like put button tag in angular statically . But I don't want to use that, because I will have multiple buttons, inputs , date picker , time picker dynamically. So please help me on this. I have been research on this from last 2 days but not getting a perfect solution. I have been use innerHtml as well . But its not working. I have used `sanitizer` , it show button now in html but its click function is not working. its not calling my function.

Statically its working but on dynamic its not working. Please check my code below.

```
<br><h4>Dynamic</h4><br>
<div contenteditable="true [innerHtml]="dyanmicHtmlString"></div><br>
<h4>Static</h4><br>
<button (click)="somefunction()">Static Button</button>

this.dyanmicHtmlString = '<button (click)="somefunction()">Dyanamic Button</button>
```

Comment: please create a stackblitz for button click problem and share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ViewChild` to add dynamic content in this case,

```
@ViewChild('myDiv', {static: false}) myDiv :ElementRef;

this.myDiv.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button (click)="somefunction()" >Dyanamic Button</button>');
```

Check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkptrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for more.

**Using DOM Sanitizer:**

```
<h4>Dynamic</h4><br>
<div contenteditable="true" [innerHTML]="dyanmicHtmlString"></div><br>

import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dyanmicHtmlString = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<button (click)="somefunction()" >Dyanamic Button</button>');
}
```

Comment: the click function inside sanitised dom is not being parsed by angular

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically add event listener with `Renderer2`, like below:

app.component.html:

```
<br>
 <h4>Dynamic</h4><br><div  [innerHtml]="dyanmicHtmlString  | safe: 'html'">
 </div><br><h4>Static</h4>
<br><button (click)="somefunction()">Static Button</button>
```

ts:

```
   name = 'Listen';
   listenerFn:any;
   dyanmicHtmlString = '<button class="dynamic" >Dyanamic Button</button>'
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

   somefunction(){
     console.log('e')
   }

   ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.listenerFn =  this.renderer.listen(document.querySelector('.dynamic'), ('click'), () =>{
       this.somefunction()
     })
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.listenerFn) {
      this.listenerFn();
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2uckbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Hope it helps!